# web3: How to be notified when address performs transaction with contract?

Tags: web3.py

Using python web3, is it possible to listen for when a given target address uses a specific contract?

For context: I want to be able to know every time a wallet purchases/sells tokens via Pancakeswap's router contract (using swapExactEthForTokens or swapExactTokensForEth).

Currently I am using bscscan's api to query for "token transfer events" via one of their APIs. But this is very limited since I am dependent on a third party's API and consequently have to use rate limited repeated http polling to check for a new event every *t* time interval.

I know something of the sort is possible via websockets and subscriptions, but I have been unable to find an example similar to mine using web3.py v6.

If anybody has any suggestions it would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use web3 to contantly listen the `transfer` event of specific token and match the `from` or `to` for the specific wallet. Working with web3 is almost same in all programing language.
Eg. in python

```
         async def log_loop(event_filter, poll_interval):
            while True:
                for Transfer in event_filter.get_new_entries():
                    handle_event(Transfer)
                await asyncio.sleep(poll_interval)
         
       
       
         def main():
            event_filter = contract.events.Transfer.createFilter(fromBlock='latest')
            #block_filter = web3.eth.filter('latest')
            # tx_filter = web3.eth.filter('pending')
            loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
            try:
                loop.run_until_complete(
                    asyncio.gather(
                        log_loop(event_filter, 2)))
                        # log_loop(block_filter, 2),
                        # log_loop(tx_filter, 2)))
            finally:
                # close loop to free up system resources
                loop.close()
```

Comment: Thank you! For something that's not a token, ie pancakeswap's router contract, does it still emit transfer events or is there another event I can listen in to?

Comment: you have to read the contract what events they emit. In pancakeswap there might be different events like `PairCreated` `Swap` `Sync` etc

Comment: Awesome, thank you for all your help!